# Get Random Data in Laravel without Repeat

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am getting question randomly by using the following method:

```
public function mcq($id)
{
    $questions = Chapter::find($id)->questions()->orderByRaw("RAND()")->paginate(1);
    return view('pages.mcq')->withQuestions($questions);
}
```

How can avoid repeat questions.

Comment: Unless there are duplicate questions in your database, this should return unique values. Also, `paginate(1)` will always return a single question, so how could there possibly be duplicates?

Comment: it means question should not repeat on all pages

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `inRandomOrder()`

```
$questions = Chapter::find($id)->questions()->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

Comment: It will not change anything, it's just a wrapper for `orderByRaw()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep the same results when using random ordering.

If you really want to make it random for each user but keep paginating working, you could create a random index and keep it in the session. Something like this:

```
session(['random' => [[1, 18, 5], [4, 3, 8], [3, 9, 14], ....]]);
```

Then use it for every page:

```
Chapter::find(1)->questions()->whereIn('id', session('random')[$pageIndex])->get();
```

You'll also need to [manually create a paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator).

Answer (score 0):

You can set currently fetched questions id in a session variable as an array.
Next time when you query for the question check for the session array and if it exists you can pass those ids in your query as

```
 ->whereNotIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
```

so that it won't repeat.

Answer (score 0):

you just can't depend on eloquent to do that , you have to add a verification layer where you can store the seen question by the user in the session and then check if id isn't in that array of already seen question 
by using something like this

```
session()->put('questions', array_merge(session('questions'), $id));
```

and then checking

```
Chapter::find($id)->questions()->whereNotIn('id',session('questions'))->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

Comment: is it possible that i will submit answer and will go back on previous question page after submitting answer? because after submitting answer i want to display answer result on same page where he submitted answer and the a report option will be appear also after submitting. any idea?

Comment: Yeah ofc , you have the access of the question or the page id , so its easy to display that page again like showing , then pass a variable that has the answer , something like this

   return view('your question view',compact('your answer variable')); 

and in the view when you display the question check if there is an answer variable is set